# Firebase callable functions with background tasks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an HTTPS callable function, that it does some logic, returns a result back, but in some cases I want to do some background work that might take a while, without waiting. At the moment it works, but I don't know if this is how it is supposed to be. Example:

```
exports.example = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // some logic //
  if(check(data,context))
    triggerSomeAsyncActions();

  return 200;
});
```

In the example above, it is important for me to return without waiting for `triggerSomeAsyncActions()`.

Comment: See the duplicate answer. Also, note that a callable Cloud Function shall not be terminated by `return 200;`. See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result

Comment: What do you mean it shall not be terminated by ```return 200;``` ?

Comment: I guess that by doing `return 200;` you try to send back a response to the user who has triggered the Cloud Function. Sending back a response to the end-user in the framework of a Callable Cloud Function will **also terminate it**. However, doing `return 200` it is not the way to send back a response to the user. I should have written my comment as "In a callable Cloud Function you should not send the response to the user by doing `return 200;`".

Comment: Well, in a callable function, anything can be returned and that is the response. Thanks also for letting me know about the other post!